# Method overloading with Parent and Child class as parameter

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overloading

I have 3 classes `GrandParent`, `Parent` and `Child`, where 
`Child extends Parent` and `Parent extends GrandParent`

```
public class Main {
    void test(GrandParent gp){System.out.println("GrandParent");}
    void test(Parent p){System.out.println("Parent");}

    public static void main(String args[]){
        GrandParent obj = new Child();
        Main mainObj = new Main();
        mainObj.test(obj);  // This calls test(GrandParent gp)

        mainObj.test(new Child()); // This calss test(Parent gp)
    }
}
```

In above code in the 2 calls to `test()` method both with `Child` object calls different methods. In one it's doing compile-time and in other run-time binding. This sounds little weird to me. How would you explain this?

Comment: Uh, seems to me like it's compile-time binding in both cases... Look up how method overloads are resolved, there should be an answer floating around on SO somewhere

Comment: It's compile time both cases...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Method overloading is compile-time polymorphism.

Method overriding is runtime polymorphism.

In your case, you are overloading two instance methods of class `Main`.

However, since I presume in your context `Child` extends `Parent`, `new Child() instanceof Parent == true` hence an instance of `Child` is a valid argument for the method `test` with argument type `Parent`.

In your first case, you pass a reference type `GrandParent` in the method `test`, and the exact type is found.

In your second case, you pass a reference type `Child` in the method `test`. The closest match is `Parent`, hence `test(Parent p)` is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting confused with your hierarchy.

The fact you say:
Child extends Parent - this means that a Child "is a" Parent.

Given the fact this does not make sense in the "real world" - it does, however, make sense in your code - you are supplying a Child object to the void test(Parent p) method - and since a Child is a Parent - this is why System.out.println("Parent") is invoked.

Comment: But a `Child` is also a `Grandparent` in this hierarchy, right? So why is the `Parent` method invoked and not the `Grandparent` method? You're technically right, but you're not quite answering OP's question.

Comment: I would assume that given another matching declaration, say - void test(Object o) that supplying a Child object would then invoke this method, due to the fact the Child class implicitly extends Object.
I could however be wrong.

Comment: Depending on if I'm thinking the same thing as you, it actually wouldn't, if you did `test(new Child())`. If you assigned `new Child()` to an `Object` and passed that, I think it would.

Answer (score -1):

Overloading means same name different parameter.
For example:

```
      class A {
          public void m1(int a) {
              System.out.println("class A");
          }
          public void m1(int a,int b) {
              System.out.prinln("2 parameter");
          }
      }
```

This is called method overloading.

Comment: That's true, but that doesn't completely answer OP's question.